# ggplot2 axis transformation by constant factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a ggplot2 density plot (geom_density) I have the following y-axis labels

- 0.000
- 0.005
- 0.010
- 0.015
- 0.020

What is the correct way to change them to something like

- 0
- 5
- 10
- 15
- 20

possibly with the automatic adding of "10^3 x density" to the label.  In the past I've just multiplied my data and manually changed the label, but in this case the y-axis data is generated for me by the density plot.

I'm aware that I can write things like `scale_y_continuous(trans="log10")`, but have not found any way to do a simple multiplicative constant, or define a custom transform.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could add the `scale_y_continuous(formatter='formatter1000')` with the following function defined before:

```
formatter1000 <- function(x){ 
    x*1000 
}
```

---

Please note, that the above answer was given one and a half year ago with a prior ggplot version. With the latest release (0.9) of ggplot the above example is not working, please try something like: `scale_y_continuous(labels = formatter1000)`

Comment: That's perfect.  Have you come across any good documentation on formatters?

Comment: @Pengin: Unfortunatelly I do not. There are some hardcoded formatters in ggplot, e.g.: comma, scientific, percent, dollar, but you could write anything with simple functions like above.

Comment: That's basically all there is too them, but in the next version they will be split out into their own package, hopefully with a bit more documentation.

Comment: Warning: This doesn't work as of `ggplot 0.9`. See my answer below for the updated version.

Comment: The `scale_y_continuous(labels = formatter1000)` note worked for me.  Notice that the `labels' argument takes a function while the `formatter` option apparently takes the name of a function as a text string.

Answer (score 40):

This answer is out of date for ggplot2 version 0.90. Now, the same format would be specified (much more neatly) this way:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x)x*1000)
```

or if you want to use the same labelling scheme multiple times:

```
formatter1000 <- function(){
  function(x)x*1000
}

scale_y_continuous(labels=formatter1000())
```

Note that if you are specifying axis limits using the `xlim` and `ylim` functions, this might not work. Instead, use the `scale_y_continuous(..., limits=c(0, 1))` specification.

There are also a bunch of built in formats in the `scales` package, including comma formatting, percentage formatting, dollar formatting and scientific notation formatting. See its [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scales/index.html) for more details.

Hope that helps someone out there, as this change certainly confused me!

Comment: Thanks.  The documentation for the scales package is nothing but the details.  What the scales package does is provide a large number of formatting functions like the `formatter1000` in this post, and to choose one of them you guess what it does from its function name.