# Bar chart with confidence interval in web application

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, bar-chart, confidence-interval

I am looking for a javascript library capable of drawing a bar chart with confidence interval.
The output should look like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13629197/1010666):

- horizontal bars
- line markers, indicating the lower and upper confidence interval.

Basically, I am looking for something similar to [candle stick / open high low closed](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/candlestick-charts.html) graph. However, the value should preferably be displayed as a horizontal bar and the independent variable is not a time series, but a set of categories.

Edit: Does anyone know if KendoUI is capable of doing this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6078785/309483

Comment: in particular, see http://www.highcharts.com/products/highstock . tell me when you saw the other question i linked

Comment: I saw the "classic" stock plots, but did not find an easy way of configuring it to achieve the look I need.

Comment: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/candlestick.html

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/4061502

Comment: because d3.js is so low level, you could quickly build the vertical variant from the source code given in the example

Answer (score 2):

[dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) has confidence intervals as you can see:

[image: dygraphs screenshot]

Comment: Yes, I have seen this one, but it is a line graph.
I need horizontal bars.

I also checked the Google charts "candle stick" but have not found an option to swap the x and y axis.

Answer (score 1):

flotr2 can do this vertically:

http://humblesoftware.com/flotr2/#!basic-candle[image: basic candle with flotr2]

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I can also not accept this as an answer, because I am looking for horizontal bars.